# How to solve an equation with 2 unknowns?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra

I am not good with advanced math but I feel like there's something I can do to solve this.
I have an equation:
$c-d = \frac{x_i-y_i}{b_i}$

Where $c$ and $x$ are unknown but I know that every $x_i = c*b_i+a_i$ and  every $y_i = d*b_i+a_i$,so no matter how  the value of unknown $x$ is changed by each iteration, the values $a$ and $b$ changes accordingly which makes $y$ change also.
So technically I have a range of unknown $x$ values with their corresponding $y$ values and the result of their subtraction is fixed ( I mean I doesn't change), so I denote this result as $z$ from now on.
So I have:
$b_1*z = x_1-y_1 = b_2*z = x_2-y_2 ... b_9*z = x_9-y_9$

Please note $b_i$ and $a_i$ are randomly selected and publicly available.
The formula which was used to create the hidden number $x_i$ is $c*b_i+a_i$ and the same formula is used for $y_i$ except with known constant $d$ replacing $c$ like this $d*b_i+a_i$.

$b_i$, $a_i$, $y_i$ and $d$ are the known values.

Someone said constructing a polynomial and finding it's root is the better attempt but I know nothing about it.
I thought of inverse matrices but then the unknown value $x$ is not constant, interchanging.

Please help with any insights on how I may attempt to solve this.
Either estimate value of $z$ or the difference between $x_i$ values e.g( $x_1$ and $x_2$)

Please be gentle I am new here.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to solve this as presented. While you can get some good estimate for $d$, there is not enough information to fix $c$ or $z$ to construct the output $x_i$ values. Is there more story around this task, more structure that restrains the $x_i$ values?

Comment: It's not obvious what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to estimate c, d and the $x_i$, or just some of those? Is your formula for $y_i$ correct too?

Comment: @Paul the estimate value of $z$ is good enough for me. I don't know the values of $c-d$ but I Know the value of $d$ so I denoted the value of $c-d$ as $z$, $x_i$ means series of different $x$ values, same applies to $y_i$

Comment: @Paul for pointing out error in formula of $y_i$ I have corrected it

Comment: If the fixed difference is $e$ then $y_i+e =cb_i+a_i$ and you can find or approximate  $c$ if you know $e$. Do you know $e$?

Comment: @Paul No, that's not possible